# Bridges between Java and .NET

Tags: java, .net, interop

I'm interested in technologies(solutions) that permits Java and .NET interoperate. I have tried the following and it works but I would like to know if there are other solutions:

- Sockets
- Web Services (Metro)
- CORBA (IIOP.NET)
- Messaging (QPid)
- IKVM

Does anyone know other technologies(solutions) that enable Java and .NET interoperate or best practices for Java and .NET interoperability?

Comment: I think you need to distinguish between interoperability within the same process, and interoperability between a Java/C# pair of processes.

Answer (score 2):

We use [Apache ActiveMQ](http://activemq.apache.org/)

Comment: @yx Interesting (+1) Can you provide some article, Tutorial about it ???

Comment: @Arthur, its very easy to use, there is a guide to get started on their website.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [j-Integra's](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/) stuff before on a few projects that served me well

Answer (score 2):

I have been working with JNBridge tools for in-process one-way JAVA Swing UI calling .NET 4.0 back end.

The whole thing performs well but does require discipline in its management. A license fee is required, so is really only a good choice when the 2 languages have to be used together.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [JNBridge](http://www.jnbridge.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it, but I have heard this works: http://jnbridge.com/